# CSS only responsive menu

Tags: html, css

I have used the W3 bits CSS-olny touch-friendly navigation menu as my base. The issue I have both on large display and small screen is the closing of the sub menu after click.
It is something to do with the checkbox hack which i have researched but cannot work out what is wrong with the code. On large and samll  display "Dropdown - 2-level DD" do not close sub menu.
Whereas "Multiple level - Another DD" work fine.   On smaller screens The only items that clear all the menu so that I end up with ' Menu    drop pointer'  is "multiple level - Another DD".  Hope you can help, otherwise I will need to create some Javascript which I am not very good at.

```css
  #menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu .main-menu {
  display: none;
}

#tm:checked+.main-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"],
#menu ul span.drop-icon {
  display: none;
}

#menu li,
#toggle-menu,
#menu .sub-menu {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

#menu li,
#toggle-menu {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
  background-color: #444;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

#menu .sub-menu li:last-child {
  border-width: 0;
}

#menu li,
#toggle-menu,
#menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

#menu {
  background-color: #09c;
}

#toggle-menu {
  background: #333;
}

#toggle-menu,
#menu a {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

#menu a {
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #09c;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu .sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

#toggle-menu .drop-icon,
#menu li label.drop-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#menu label.drop-icon,
#toggle-menu span.drop-icon {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #menu .main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #toggle-menu,
  #menu label.drop-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu ul span.drop-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #menu li {
    float: left;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  }
  #menu .sub-menu li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu .sub-menu {
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 12em;
    z-index: 3000;
  }
  #menu .sub-menu,
  #menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu .sub-menu li {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  #menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
  #menu .sub-menu .drop-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  #menu li:hover>input[type="checkbox"]+.sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<div class=class="wrapper">
  <nav id="menu">
    <label for="tm" id="toggle-menu">Menu <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tm">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm0">&#9662</label>
      </a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sm0">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1.4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2-level DD 
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm1">&#9662</label>
      </a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sm1">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2.2
            <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm2">&#9662</label>
          </a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sm2">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Item 2.2.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2.2.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2.2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Multiple Levels
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm3">&#9662</label>
    </a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sm3">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="">3.1
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm4">&#9662</label>
      </a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sm4">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="">3.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.1.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.1.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.1.4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">3.2
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm5">&#9662</label>
      </a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sm5">
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="">3.2.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.2.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">3.3
          <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm6">&#9662</label>
          </a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sm6">
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="">3.3.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.3.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.2.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.3.4</a></li>
              <li><a href="">3.3.5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another DD
          <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm8">&#9662</label>
          </a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sm8">
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="">4.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">4.4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  < </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Reproducing your issue is hard. Consider adding a recorded clip.

Comment: How do you add a recorded clip to this question.

Comment: I have just worked out what is wrong with the Large screen display. If you remove the # from the Dropdown and 2nd Level menu it works fine. I think there is still an issue with the small screen display. will have to do some more testing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good to know, you have figured out the solution. Talking of recorded clip, record a video showing the issue with recording software like OBS. Upload it to an image hosting website like Imgur. And finally, add a link to the video in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I could understand your problem, I tried editing your code.

```css
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu .main-menu {
    display: none;
}

#tm:checked+.main-menu {
    display: block;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"],
#menu ul span.drop-icon {
    display: none;
}

#menu li,
#toggle-menu,
#menu .sub-menu {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

#menu li,
#toggle-menu {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
    background-color: #444;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

#menu .sub-menu li:last-child {
    border-width: 0;
}

#menu li,
#toggle-menu,
#menu a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

#menu {
    background-color: #09c;
}

#toggle-menu {
    background: #333;
}

#toggle-menu,
#menu a {
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

#menu a {
    transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #09c;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}

#menu .sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #444;
}

#toggle-menu .drop-icon,
#menu li label.drop-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#menu label.drop-icon,
#toggle-menu span.drop-icon {
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #menu .main-menu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #toggle-menu,
    #menu label.drop-icon {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu ul span.drop-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #menu li {
        float: left;
        border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
    }
    #menu .sub-menu li {
        float: none;
    }
    #menu .sub-menu {
        border-width: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 12em;
        z-index: 3000;
    }
    #menu .sub-menu,
    #menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.sub-menu {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu .sub-menu li {
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    #menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
    #menu .sub-menu .drop-icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    #menu li:hover>input[type="checkbox"]+.sub-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="help2.css" />
<div class=class="wrapper">
    <nav id="menu">
        <label for="tm" id="toggle-menu">Menu <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tm">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm0">&#9662</label>
      </a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sm0">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 1.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 1.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 1.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2-level DD 
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm1">&#9662</label>
      </a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sm1">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item 2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.2
            <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm2">&#9662</label>
          </a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm2">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Item 2.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Item 2.2.2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Item 2.2.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Multiple Levels
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm3">&#9662</label>
    </a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sm3">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">3.1
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm4">&#9662</label>
      </a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm4">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">3.1.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.1.2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.1.3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.1.4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">3.2
        <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
        <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm5">&#9662</label>
      </a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm5">
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">3.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.2.2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.2.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">3.3
          <span class="drop-icon">&#9656</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm6">&#9662</label>
          </a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm6">
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">3.3.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.3.2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.2.2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.3.4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3.3.5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sample #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another DD
          <span class="drop-icon">&#9662</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm8">&#9662</label>
          </a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sm8">
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">4.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">4.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">4.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">4.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    < </div>
        </body>
```